# Custom cleric domain

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, cleric, homebrew, domains

Is there a way to create a custom domain for clerics? I remember reading about it way back, but I don't remember the exact book.

Comment: What are you looking for? Do you want game-design guidance, or guidelines for DMs, or some kind of player-accessible blurb similar to the one about researching spells?

Comment: guidelines, game-design, guidelines and player blurb is all good answers, just trying to find it. It was a rule though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general feat **Customize Domain** (*Dragon* #325 61) has as its prerequisites that the creature A) possess at least one domain, and B) that the creature can cast 3rd-level divine spells. The feat's benefit says

> Choose one of your cleric domains. You permanently exchange spells on your domain spell list for similar spells on any spell list you have access to. You customize your domain when you choose this feat; you cannot later change your domain spells or return to your original domain spell list. You can only choose to substitute spells that are of equal or lower level and that adhere to the following restrictions by domain. Note that certain spells gain descriptors depending on how they’re cast; you can choose such a spell as a spell with the descriptor you require so long as you only cast the spell in such a manner as to give it that descriptor.

The feat's benefit then provides examples of restrictions, like the domain [Magic](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/clericDomains.html#magic-domain) allows picking "[a]ny kind of spell, but you must select a spell one level lower than normal, and the domain [Travel](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/clericDomains.html#travel-domain) that allows "[s]pells that alter speed or provide movement."

Comment: Similarly, the June 2007 Mind's Eye Web column ["Expanded Classes, Part Four: Ardent, Divine Mind, Lurk, and Erudite"](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/psm/20070629a) grants the *Complete Psionic* base class **ardent** the class feature **substitute powers**, permitting the ardent to "add further powers to fill the gaps if [a] mantle [n.b. a mantle closely resembles a cleric's domain] has no powers of that level. The powers need to fit the theme of the mantle at the DM's discretion."